# Show that $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x+cy)=f(x)+cf(y), \forall \,x,y \in \mathbb{R},\,\forall \,c \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

My try:
We need to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a), \forall a\in\mathbb{R}$.
At first, I tried to show that $f$ is continuous at $0$ and from there I would show for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. I already managed to prove the second part assuming that $f$ is continuous at $0$, but I can't see how to prove the first part.  I only got that $f(0)=0$. I'm very confused, I appreciate any help!

Comment: $$\lim\limits_{c\to0}f(x+c)=\lim\limits_{c\to0}f(x)+c f(1)=f(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

"f is continuous in R" means that, for every a in r, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)= f(a)$.  Let u= x- a so that becomes $\lim_{u\to 0} f(a+ u)= f(a)$.  If $f(a+ u)= f(a)+ f(u)$  that reduces to $\lim_{u\to 0} f(a)+ f(u)= f(a)+ \lim_{u\to 0} f(u)= f(a)$ so $\lim_{u\to 0} f(u)= 0$.

Comment: I don't get it, in this case you're assuming that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$?

Comment: That is part if "f is continuous at a"!